# Increasing our number of questions posted

Tags: discussion, statistics

Today, I was comparing our [current stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia) with those of [Mathematica.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica) when it graduated. It is good to see that **most numbers are very similar, except for the *number of questions asked per day***.

I can see how that would be different, with Mathematica being a site where people asks many shorter questions, while ours tend to be on the longer side (and we have more answers per question).

Now the question I had (more like, the discussion I wanted to start, really) is: **do we need to let this number grow on its own, as traffic will increase, or is there something we can/want to do to help it increase?**

Comment: This sounds very similar to a [previous question of yours](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/258/when-is-an-edit-not-an-edit-any-more) :)  As I recall, we chose to lean towards closing & subsequent deletion rather than editing just for the purpose of `postcount++`.

Comment: @eykanal the last part is, true… let me remove it and let the broader question stand

Comment: Related http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/273/why-arent-more-questions-being-asked. Now that is it 3 months later has your opinion changed?

Answer (score 3):

Another question might also be whether we should also expect a higher number of questions. It's of course hard to compare different SE, but to some extent, I would say we have a community closer to that of [CS Theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) rather than [CS](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science). I don't have the exact numbers for CSTheory, but a quick look at their question list seems to show that they have around 7 questions per day (at least in the last 5 or 6 days).

In other words, by excluding undergrad questions, we chose to have a community homogenous, rather than a bunch of experts answering a lot of "simple" questions (this is clearly an over-simplified, exaggerated interpretation). My point is that I'm not sure if we should expect to reach the 15 questions per day anytime soon, but at the same time, I believe we have started to build quite a nice community.

Comment: The current stats for cstheory can be found here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8766/theoretical-computer-science. Indeed, we are relatively close to their stats.

Comment: @walkmanyi: I believe that these are the stats at the end of the beta, so they might be a bit outdated. But indeed, their stats were quite close to ours at the launch of the site.

Comment: I see. It was not that obvious from looking at the page. Thanks for the explanation.